# Limiting text to certain number of characters ignoring HTML tags/attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text block like this:

```
<p class="post">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="http://website.com/link" target="_blank" title="hello">consectetur adipiscing elit</a>. Pellentesque vehicula tortor eget tortor fermentum bibendum. Duis mollis nisl et metus vulputate, a aliquam quam pharetra. <a href="http://website.com/link" target="_blank" title="hello">consectetur adipiscing elit</a> quis hendrerit nibh ultrices eget. <span class="highlight">Praesent</span> eu mollis lectus, sed convallis quam.</p>
```

I want to truncate that text after 100 characters. With just a text string I would use something like:

```
var new_string = text_string.substring(0,100);
```

But I need to take the links and other HTML within the text into account when counting the characters so that it truncates the text after 100 *visible* characters, not 100 characters of the HTML itself, and **retains the HTML tags within the text**.

**Note:** I can't leave any HTML tags open, so I need to either not truncate the text until the open tag is closed, or truncate the text and then add the correct closing tag.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You can traverse the nodes in document order, and whenever you arrive at a text node, see how many characters it has. Keep a running total, and when you get to the node that takes you over the maximum, truncate there and then empty every subsequent text node.

Comment: you can to run regex to find all the text that between ><.

Comment: Are you wanting to strip out the html? Or truncate the text and leave the html? This is usually done after stripping out the html because it isn't easy to just count text and still have valid html without a bunch of empty html tags or formatting that could potentially blow up the layout.

Comment: I need to retain the HTML tags as much as possible, so either not truncating the text until a tag has been closed or truncating the text and then adding the correct closing tag if an element is unclosed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip all the html tags from the string with a regex and then substring

```
var new_string = text_string.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "").substring(0,100);
```

**[UPDATE] I read about the retains of HTML code, the only solution that I thought is this:**

```
var regx = new RegExp(/(<[^>]*>)/g);
var counter = 0;

//convert the string in array using the HTML tags as delimiter and keeping they as array elements
strArray = str.split(regx);

for (var i = 0, len = strArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    //ignore the array elements that is HTML tags
    if ( !(regx.test(strArray[i])) ) {
        //if the counter is 100, remove this element with text
        if (counter == 100) {
          strArray.splice(i, 1);
          continue; //ignore next commands and continue the for loop
        }
        //if the counter != 100, increase the counter with this element length
        counter = counter + strArray[i].length;
        //if is over 100, slice the text of this element to match the total of 100 chars and set the counter to 100
        if (counter > 100) {
          var diff = counter - 100;
          strArray[i] = strArray[i].slice(0, -diff);
          counter = 100;
        }
    }
}

//new string from the array
new_string = strArray.join('');

//remove empty html tags from the array
new_string = new_string.replace(/(<(?!\/)[^>]+>)+(<\/[^>]+>)/g, "");
```

Live example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/davebra/pen/XNGWJx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that I need to retain any HTML tags in the text rather than just stripping them out and truncating the text.

Comment: Sorry I didn't red that. The only solution that I can think is to split the string in an array using the regex of the html tags a "splitter", then with a for loop, count the chars only of the elements with text using a counter variable, then break or remove the element with text when the counter is 100. I post a code with comments.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and it seems to work perfectly! You're the man! Thanks so much - it's really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it

```
var html = 'YOUR HTML STRING'
var elt = document.createElement('container');
elt.innerHTML = html;
var text = elt.textContent;
var result = text.substring(0,100);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that I need to retain any HTML tags in the text rather than just stripping them out and truncating the text.

Answer (score 0):

If str is you string use this to get all the text.

```js
var str = '<p class="post">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="http://website.com/link" target="_blank" title="hello">consectetur adipiscing elit</a>. Pellentesque vehicula tortor eget tortor fermentum bibendum. Duis mollis nisl et metus vulputate, a aliquam quam pharetra. <a href="http://website.com/link" target="_blank" title="hello">consectetur adipiscing elit</a> quis hendrerit nibh ultrices eget. <span class="highlight">Praesent</span> eu mollis lectus, sed convallis quam.</p>'
var allTheText = str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g,"")
console.log(allTheText.length)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that I need to retain any HTML tags in the text rather than just stripping them out and truncating the text.

Comment: @john you can get the length of allTheText, find the last chars that you want remove , find it in the original string and remove all the strings after it.